# Create a new CSV file for every 100 tweets

Tags: python, csv, twitter

**Goal:**  I want to create a new csv file for every 100 tweets. So, once I collect 100 tweets, I want the csv file to close, and I want a new a new CSV file to open and collect another 100 tweets.

**Problem:** I'm only getting 1 tweet per csv file. That is, 1 tweet is collect and the csv file closes, and a new csv file is created again with 1 tweet,  and the process continues.

I've tried googling around and changing my code but it still does the same. Any insight would be helpful. Thanks!

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, api=None,fprefix = 'streamer'):
        super(StdOutListener, self).__init__()
        self.num_tweets = 0
        self.fprefix = fprefix
        self.output  = open(fprefix + '.' 
                            + time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') + '.csv', 'w')
        self.writer = csv.writer(self.output, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')

    def on_data(self, data):
        t = json.loads(data)
        tweet_id = t['id_str'] 
        dt = t['created_at']  
        user_name = t['user']['name']
        text = t['text']
        created = datetime.datetime.strptime(dt, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y')
        tweet = {'tweet_id':tweet_id,'created_at':created,'user_name':user_name,'user_screenName ':user_screenName ,'user_id': user_id, 'user_location': user_location, 'text':text,'expanded_url':expanded_url}

        self.num_tweets += 1
        if self.num_tweets >= 100:
            self.output.write(data + "\n")
            collection.save(tweet)
            self.output.close()
            self.output = open('/Users/edwinreyes/Desktop/' + self.fprefix + '.' 
                               + time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') + '.csv', 'w')
            self.counter = 0

        return
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not writing `tweet` to anything except when `num_tweets` is equal to `100`.

The only time it is writing to the file is in your if-statement block.

Comment: any suggestions on how to improve the code to write to `tweet` ?

Comment: After you have assembled the `tweet` into a string.  Put `self.output.write(tweet)`  Put it before the if-statement.

Comment: `tweet = {some info}
  self.output.seek(0)
   self.output.write(tweet)`

Comment: I tried the following code per your suggestion but I get a `TypeError: expected a string or other character buffer object`   Maybe this is not what you meant?

Comment: I used `self.output.seek(0)` to convert `tweet` into a string. But I still get the error

Comment: I also tried `self.output.write(str(tweet))` and that didnt work

Comment: Try self.writer.writerow(tweet)